# How do I open window from another that's already open?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a file with 2 classes defining UI: main one and secondary. I have main program that imports from this main_GUI.py:

```
from main_GUI import Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke
from main_GUI import Ui_dodaj_autora
```

and shows the main window:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke):
    def __init__(self):
       QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
       self.ui = Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

At some point in the program I have defined function where if user chooses certain option from list it opens new window (2nd class in GUI.py):

```
def autorchange(self):

    item = self.ui.autor.currentText()
    nazwisko, imie = item.split()
    if item == "Dodaj autora...":
        #this is where program is supposed to show second window for user to interact with
```

How do I show this window so I can perform my other actions on it?

This new window has two text fields for user to write values which are next supposed to be inserted into SQL database and window should close.

I tried to use, same as for main windoww but it failed with error:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to Main "dodaj_autora", which already has a layout Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\jakub\PycharmProjects\biblioteka\main.py", line 46, in autorchange
    self.ui.setupUi(self)   File "C:\Users\jakub\PycharmProjects\biblioteka\main_GUI.py", line 231, in setupUi
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(dodaj_autora.accept) AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'accept'
```

I also tried different approach. I created new class:

```
class Autor(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_dodaj_autora):
    def __init__(self):
       QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
       self.ui = Ui_dodaj_autora()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Then inside the Main class and definition of function checking which option from the list was chosen by user:

```
def autorchange(self):

    item = self.ui.autor.currentText()
    nazwisko, imie = item.split()
    if item == "Dodaj autora...":
        print("Dodawanie autora")
        okno = Autor()
        okno.show()
return item
```

But this also ends up with error:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to Autor "dodaj_autora", which already has a layout
```

I have prepared the minimal code needed to run the program. It can be found here:
debug.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from debug_GUI import Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke
from debug_GUI import Ui_dodaj_autora


class Autor(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_dodaj_autora):
    def __init__(self):
       QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
       self.ui = Ui_dodaj_autora()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke):
    def __init__(self):
       QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
       self.ui = Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def pole_autor(self):

        self.ui.autor.addItem("Wybierz autora...")
        self.ui.autor.addItem("Dodaj autora...")

        self.ui.autor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.autorchange)

    def autorchange(self):

        item = self.ui.autor.currentText()

        if item == "Dodaj autora...":
            print("Dodawanie autora")
            okno = Autor()
            okno.show()
        return item

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.pole_autor()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and debug_GUI.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dodaj_Ksiazke):
        Dodaj_Ksiazke.setObjectName("Dodaj_Ksiazke")
        Dodaj_Ksiazke.resize(450, 600)
        Dodaj_Ksiazke.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(450, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dodaj_Ksiazke)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.autor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.autor.setObjectName("autor")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.autor, 3, 2, 1, 1)

        Dodaj_Ksiazke.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Dodaj_Ksiazke)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dodaj_Ksiazke)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dodaj_Ksiazke):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dodaj_Ksiazke.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dodaj_Ksiazke", "Dodaj Książkę"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dodaj_Ksiazke", "Autor"))

class Ui_dodaj_autora(object):
    def setupUi(self, dodaj_autora):
        dodaj_autora.setObjectName("dodaj_autora")
        dodaj_autora.resize(400, 100)
        dodaj_autora.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 100))
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(dodaj_autora)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(dodaj_autora)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(dodaj_autora)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dodaj_autora)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dodaj_autora)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(dodaj_autora)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.retranslateUi(dodaj_autora)

    def retranslateUi(self, dodaj_autora):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dodaj_autora.setWindowTitle(_translate("dodaj_autora", "Dodaj Autora"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("dodaj_autora", "Nazwisko"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("dodaj_autora", "Imię"))
```

You need to click the dropdown list and choose "Dodaj autora...". This should open new window that's defined in debug_GUI.py - it's the class "Ui_dodaj_autora"

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/hyperqbe/rezEBa - GUI
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/hyperqbe/Ee9gGE - main program

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete and testable example?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are requesting, but I tried to use `self.ui.setupUi(self)` but it failed with below error.

 `   def autorchange(self):

        item = self.ui.autor.currentText()
        nazwisko, imie = item.split()
        if item == "Dodaj autora...":
            print("Dodawanie autora")
            self.ui = Ui_dodaj_autora()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)

      return item`

Comment: @HyperQBE We need to test your code to know where the error is, so we require a [mcve], if you do not know what it is then check the link. please read [ask]

Comment: @S.Nick you can use `[mcve]` and the complete message will be generated next to the link: [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc ah, now I understand, I'm sorry. I'll get this as soon as possible.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added links to code snippets required to run the program, hope it helps.

Comment: Do not add links to show code as they can be broken making your question unusable for future readers, the links are only backup and can not replace the main part of your question: your code.

Comment: I've added code directly to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- Your code is redundant in the inheritance:

  ```
  [1.] class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke): 
  [2.]     def __init__(self):
  [3.]        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
  [4.]        self.ui = Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke()
  [5.]        self.ui.setupUi(self)
  ```

In the line `[1.]` you are inheriting from `Ui_dodaj_autora`, and in the line `[4.]` you are creating an object of the class, why are you doing that ?, it does not make sense, so you must one of the following 2 options:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

---

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

- On the other hand when you use Qt Designer you choose templates so when you want to use a class it must correspond with that choice, for example in the case of `Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke` you have used the Main Window template so you must use `QMainWindow`, in the case of `Ui_dodaj_autora` you have used *Dialog with Buttons Bottom* so you should use `QDialog`.
- QDialogButtonBox must connect the accepted and rejected signal to the accept and reject slots of QDialog.
- When using a `QDialog` that serves to have a dialog to ask the user to provide data you must use `exec_()` to know if the request is accepted or not.

Considering the above, the following answer is obtained:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from debug_GUI import Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke, Ui_dodaj_autora


class Autor(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_dodaj_autora):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autor, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Dodaj_Ksiazke):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def pole_autor(self):
        self.autor.addItems(["Wybierz autora...", "Dodaj autora..."])
        self.autor.currentTextChanged.connect(self.autorchange)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def autorchange(self, text):
        if text == "Dodaj autora...":
            print("Dodawanie autora")
            okno = Autor()
            if okno.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
                print(okno.lineEdit.text(), okno.lineEdit_2.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.pole_autor()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I'm a newbie when it comes to Python. Some of this code was written based on what I have found online, so it's possible I was repeating mistakes. Code itself was working until this point so I didn't know it was redundant. Now I have to correct the main progam and implement function in the new window that will update SQL database with new entry and refresh list.